# Kafka metrics about message conversion

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm currently using Kafka and Zookeeper of the confluent platform version 4.0.0 and I'm using the Kafka producer version 1.0.1.

When I'm having a look at the Kafka broker metrics I see that the metric called

> kafka_network_request_metrics_message_conversions_time_ms{request="Produce",}

is increasing, but the metrics

> kafka_server_broker_topic_metrics_fetch_message_conversions_total

and

> kafka_server_broker_topic_metrics_produce_message_conversions_total

are still on 0 and are not increasing. I have absolutely no clue why this happens and what that means and I also haven't found anything related in the documentation. The one metric says that message conversion is happening but the other metric is saying the opposite. Can somebody of you explain that?

I'm also not sure why message conversion should happen, because as far as I know confluent platform 4.0.0 is using Kafka version 1.0.0 and this should be compatible with 1.0.1. Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey guys, I'm still having that problem and I'm not sure why the message conversion happens. Can anyone help me?